# JQuery Validation in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I use this JQuery code to disabled submit button when user click on it, in the form in my MVC3 Project.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
     $(':submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})
```

I use jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js for validate errors in my form, and when there is a validation error the submit button is disabled. but i want to remove disabled attribute when the validation error occurs. how can i Distinguish the validation error was happened in my code?

Comment: You want to remove the disabled attribute when there are validation errors? So, when do you want to disable the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. 
this is the jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':submit',this).attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```